# Does latest Cassandra support openJDK?

Tags: cassandra

On the GitHub Readme it says Tested on >=1.7 (OpenJSK and Sun). However, when I looked at `CassandraDaemon.java`, the warning that asks us to upgrade to Oracle Java still exists.

Can someone comment on this ?

Answer (score 4):

I am sure DataStax does testing against OpenJDK, but it is a recommendation to use Sun JDK. There are several people on Community who use OpenJDK without problems but there are also some who do have a lot of problems with openJDK. If you read a few lines later where you started:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blame/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/CassandraDaemon.java#L119

You see one example that it warns about what may not work as intended if non-Sun-JDK is used. Those usually affect performance and GC. So, use OpenJDK at your own risk. Also latest version required Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use Oracle JDK. We encountered issues because the version was not named in an acceptable format for an OpenJDK implementation i.e. it used icedtea in version and the script could not handle this scenario.

Comment: Completely agree.  I don't even recommend OpenJDK for Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of cassandra 1.2 does not list openJDK as an option under pre-requisites, but it does in cassandra 2.0 and 2.1:

"Latest version of Oracle Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) 8 (recommended) or OpenJDK 7."

From:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html